# what knid of usage " [MenuAction("apply", "global-menus/MenuTools/MenuToolsMyTools/Tool1", "Apply")]"?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-3.0

MenuAction,ButtonAction,... etc why i need this type usage. i really what it is  [ButtonAction("apply", "global-toolbars/ToolbarMyTools/Tool1", "Apply")]. Can you give me some tips or advise or site link. i don't really know [Myclass]. is it AOP?

```
 [MenuAction("apply", "global-menus/MenuTools/MenuToolsMyTools/Tool1", "Apply")]

    // Declares a toolbar button action with action ID "apply"
    // TODO: Change the action path hint to your desired toolbar path, or
    // remove this attribute if you do not want to create a toolbar button for this tool
    [ButtonAction("apply", "global-toolbars/ToolbarMyTools/Tool1", "Apply")]

    // Specifies tooltip text for the "apply" action
    // TODO: Replace tooltip text
    [Tooltip("apply", "Place tooltip text here")]

    // Specifies icon resources to use for the "apply" action
    // TODO: Replace the icon resource names with your desired icon resources
    [IconSet("apply", IconScheme.Colour, "Icons.Tool1Small.png", "Icons.Tool1Medium.png", "Icons.Tool1Large.png")]

    // Specifies that the enablement of the "apply" action in the user-interface
    // is controlled by observing a boolean property named "Enabled", listening to
    // an event named "EnabledChanged" for changes to this property
    [EnabledStateObserver("apply", "Enabled", "EnabledChanged")]
```

Answer (score 0):

These are Attributes - they don't do anything by themselves, but you can approach them by using Reflection.

There probably is some framework-type of thing that parses these attributes and creates the menus and tooltips for you.

Comment: Can you give some detail or samples or links?

Comment: Here's the tutorial on MSDN, It's explained around an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(VS.71).aspx